# Python->Sybase db how create a connection easily

Tags: python

Im trying to looking for an easy sample for test sybase connection with python

- I try python-sybase module it falls with this error  C:\I1639425203\include does not exist - cannot build
  "C:\I1639425203" is the folder where I install the sybase package i had
  [image]
- I try pyodbc but I also have alot errors or the conection keeps fronzee
- I try pymssql but it keeps frozee and the connection never ends.
- I try

**update 2021-12-14**

finally,I figure out how configure sqlanydb from SAP and install it in a VENV with poetry ( I come from java is like maven)  with python 3.9[image: succes install driver] and it works. but pymssql not works yet

repo with the test
https://github.com/Qleoz12/python-sybase-Demo

Comment: Could you share the pieces of code where you tried the several modules? Maybe it's a parameter you missed

Comment: i will update and create a repo with the code